# Query works on SQLite Browser but not in Android SQlLite

Tags: android, string, sqlite

I'm writting you because I having tried to find out how to get this query works on Android, I know that the sintaxis is OK, because i have tried on SQLite Browser before but I don't know why it doesn't give me any result on Android, this is the code that I'm using on Android:

```
    public long getAdminOrMemberOrGroupID (String arg, char option){
    Cursor result = null;
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { arg };
    long idResult = 0;
    int idIndex=0;

    switch(option){
    case 'a':
        result = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id FROM Admins WHERE mac=?", selectionArgs);
        //result = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id FROM Admins WHERE mac= '"+ arg +"'", null);
        //result = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE_ADMINS, new String[]{KEY_ID}, KEY_MAC + "= '" + arg + "'" , null, null, null, null); 
    case 'm':
        result = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id FROM Members WHERE mac=?", selectionArgs);
        //result = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id FROM Members WHERE mac= '"+ arg +"'", null);
        //result = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE_MEMBERS, new String[]{KEY_ID}, KEY_MAC + "= '" + arg + "'", null, null, null, null);
    case 'g':
        result = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id FROM Groups WHERE name=?", selectionArgs);
        ////result = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id FROM Groups WHERE name= '"+ arg +"'", null);
        //result = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE_GROUPS, new String[]{KEY_ID}, KEY_NAME + "= '" + arg + "'", null, null, null, null);

    }

    idIndex = result.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID);

    if(result!=null){
        if (result.isFirst()){
             idResult= result.getLong(idIndex);
        }
    }

    return idResult;
}
```

As you have seen, I have tried to do it in several ways but none of them works fine, it doesn't return any result. I have pulled the database file to my pc using DDMS and trying the same query on SQLite Browser and this works. So, where is the problem on the code shown before?

Thanks for any help on this issue,

Tim, here it is:

```
public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
public static final int NAME_COLUMN = 1;
public static final String KEY_MAC = "mac";
public static final int MAC_COLUMN = 2;
public static final String KEY_GPS = "gps";
public static final int GPS_COLUMN = 3;
public static final String KEY_ID_ADMIN = "idAdmin";
public static final String KEY_ID_GROUP = "idGroup";

private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_ADMINS = "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE_ADMINS + 
"(" + KEY_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + KEY_NAME + " text not null, " + KEY_MAC + " text not null);";
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_GROUPS = "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE_GROUPS + 
"(" + KEY_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + KEY_ID_ADMIN + " integer, " + KEY_NAME + " text not null);";
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_MEMBERS = "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE_MEMBERS + 
"(" + KEY_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + KEY_NAME + " text not null, " + KEY_MAC + " text not null, " 
    + KEY_GPS + " text, " + KEY_ID_GROUP + " integer);";
```

Method that creates the tables

```
public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

    if(dbExist){
        //do nothing - database already exist
    }else{
        db = context.openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASE_NAME, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_ADMINS);
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_MEMBERS);
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_GROUPS);
    }

}

private boolean checkDataBase(){

    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

    try{
        String myPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }catch(SQLiteException e){

        //database does't exist yet.

    }

    if(checkDB != null){

        checkDB.close();

    }

    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: I would debug the application in Android and check that everything passed into the method is correct and the constructed query is what you expect/tested in SQLite Browser.

Comment: Where did you create/define your tables, inside Android or outside of Android using SQLite Browser? Can you post your table defs?

Comment: I certainly did already, that's what I have been doing for a time before posting, the code has been tested (using the debugger) under the types of queries, and I have tried the sql sentence given by the debugger on SQLite Brower and it gives the desired result on that application

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Documentation says that returned cursor object is positioned before first entry.  I think that isFirst in this case will always return false.
result.moveToFirst()?
Check returned entries count.

Comment: Deucalion is correct - in the documentation for `rawQuery` it says that the cursor returned points to **before** the first row. So if you replace `if (result.isFirst())` with `if (result.moveToFirst())`, your problem should be resolved.

Comment: Thanks @PresidentEvil. It worked but can you please explain why do i have to call moveToFirst()?

Comment: @ManishNegi before you interact with the Cursor, it doesn't point to any row in particular, and you need to move it to an entry. The most common use case is to start at the first result, hence `moveToFirst()`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you get an error or just no results?
Are you sure the data is in the database?

Comment: I dont't get any errors, is just return an 0. And yes, I have pulled the database (as a copy) from the emulator using DDMS just before entering with the debugger into this part of my code, and when I open it with SQLite Browser i can see android_metadata, Groups, Members and Admins tables with information on it. I can tell you also that the "arg" is a variable that it's obtained after doing another query in another part of the code, and when I'm doing the debugging it gives me a value that's not null

Answer (score 0):

Have you setup your sqlite database with android_metadata table? See [that post](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/), it might help. For my app I'm using the database helper class from that post and it's working like a charm.

Comment: Yes that's done, it's configured under en_US, anyway I had seen that post already, and the dabase show that table as well.